# CMD arguments in C# - freeze

Tags: c#, cmd

I try to make some easy GUI for wifi hotspot but after click on the button on, it didn't write to the textBox1 and window go to freeze. I didn't try button_off yet.

I'll be glad for any tips. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
    namespace Wifi_hotspot
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private String name, password;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_on_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo zapnout = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
        zapnout.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        zapnout.UseShellExecute = false;
        zapnout.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        zapnout.CreateNoWindow = true;
        zapnout.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        var info = Process.Start(zapnout);

        info.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + name + " key=" + password);
        info.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan start hostednetwork");
        string s = info.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        info.Close();

        textBox1.Text = s;
    }

    private void button_off_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo vypnout = new ProcessStartInfo();
        vypnout.UseShellExecute = false;
        vypnout.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        vypnout.CreateNoWindow = true;
        vypnout.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        var info = Process.Start(vypnout);

        info.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan stop hostednetwork");
        string s = info.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        textBox1.Text = s;
    }

    private void textBox_ssid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox_ssid.TextLength > 0 && textBox_heslo.TextLength > 0)
        {
            enableBtn(true);
            name = textBox_ssid.Text;
            password = textBox_heslo.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            enableBtn(false);
        }
    }

    private void enableBtn(bool enable)
    {
        button_on.Enabled = enable;
        button_off.Enabled = enable;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A window will freeze because it is processing something that takes many cycles. Generally operations like this need another thread if the freezing gets bad enough. With regards to your button_off and button_on, you can simplify this by changing enableBtn to this

`private void toggleBtn() { button.Enabled = !button.Enabled; }`

My suggestion is to follow the line of processing. Put a breakpoint on a button click function, and then walk through every line to see if it is looping anywhere, or is waiting for something that won't finish.

Comment: This may seem like the easy/obvious way to go but I'd probably look at P/Invoking the actual Win32 functions rather than using `cmd` and `wsh` as intermediaries. E.g. your first `wlan` call looks like it would be two calls to [WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439495(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Looking again at your code - you're trying to start an interactive `cmd` instance, sending it two commands and then nothing else. Then you call `ReadToEnd` on its standard output - but it's never going to signal that its finished outputting because it doesn't know to quit and so it may (reasonably) still expect to receive more commands from you.

Comment: Thank you guys! Problem were in this missing line:       info.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

Comment: @Jaccob - I'd still recommend that you look into changing over to using the actual API rather than using these intermediary processes. For starters, you wouldn't need to introduce bizarre waiting inside your process, for second, you'd get usable feedback rather than (if you attempt it at all) trying to discern outcomes by parsing string output.